# Nautilus 3.18.2 and Google Drive

Tags: gnome, nautilus, ubuntu-gnome, google-drive

I am currently running Nautilus 3.18.2 and one of the announced features was that there will be Google Drive support after Online Accounts have been properly set up. So after adding in my Google account I noticed that the drive is not being displayed in the file manager at all. Is there a way to fix this without the user of other programs like rclone, rsync and the likes. Running GNOME 3.18.2 on Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Did you install also `gvfs-google` and `gvfs-goa` from the same repository you got Gnome 3.18?

Comment: The repository used to install Gnome 3.18 were `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` and `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`.  `gvfs-google` and `gvfs-goa` where not installed and when I tried to apt says "Unable to locate package" @dadexix86

Comment: Then you should just wait that they provide it :) the integration of Google Drive in Nautilus is provided in these two packages. Without them, it will not work :)